# Is there a way to use a function in withStateHandlers in other component?

Tags: reactjs

```
const Map = compose(
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        isOpen: false,
        markerIndex: 0
    }), {
        onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => (index) => ({
            isOpen: true,
            markerIndex: index
        })
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)
```

I want to call the onToggleOpen in another class, is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `onToggleOpen` into a function, and export it to use in another file.

```
const onToggleOpen = ({ isOpen }) => index => ({
  isOpen: true,
  markerIndex: index
});

const Map = compose(
  withStateHandlers(() => ({ isOpen: false, markerIndex: 0 }), {
    onToggleOpen
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
);

// ES6 module syntax
export { onToggleOpen };
// CJS syntax
modules.exports = { onToggleOpen };
```